# Dual high-side switch is not shutting off as expected

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Clearly I am having trouble understanding transistors and MOSFETs, and their datasheets.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBQpyn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using an ESP32's GPIO (3.3V at 40mA) to control an NPN transistor ([2N2222](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf)) which, in turn, controls two P-channel MOSFETs ([IRF4905](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF4905-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e329b1197e)). For now, V1 is provided by a 12V/3A brick and V2 is pulled from the 5V of the USB powering the ESP32. All the negatives are tied together.

When the GPIO is HIGH, I expect the gate voltage to be near zero which the simulation and my probe confirm is happening. I expect M1 to have `Vgs = 0 - 12.25 = -12.25V` and M2 to have `Vgs = 0 - 5.2 = -5.2V`, resulting in both being ON since both are less that -4V.

When the GPIO is LOW, I expect the gate voltage to be 12.25V so M1 can experience `Vgs = 12.25 - 12.25 = 0V` and M2, `Vgs = 12.25 - 5.2 = 7.05V`. Since both are greater than -2V, I expect both the MOSFETs to be OFF; the simulation corroborates that.

However, in practice, when the GPIO is LOW, neither of the MOSFETs are going OFF. Probing the voltage between the gate and the ground, I get 8.92V (without the Peltier and the fan connected). If my voltmeter had an internal resistance of 3M ohms, that would make sense but I used a 1M ohms resister in series with the voltmeter and that told me it had an internal resistance of nearly 12M ohms. So in reality, the gate was sitting at 9.67V.

A. I am having a hard time explaining the 9.67V when I expected 12.25V. What could be causing that and how do I solve it?

B. Even if I accept that 9.67V is the actual voltage at the gate, I expect M2 to have `Vgs = 9.67 - 5.2 = 4.47V` which is greater than -2V. I expect M2 to be OFF and am having a hard time explaining why it is not.

My goal is *not* to make the best possible circuit for controlling the Peltier and fan. I am trying to learn about transistors and MOSFETs by making "something" that helps me understand them. I would be grateful for any tips and pointers.

---

**Update:** Thanks to @Transistor and @TimWilliams, I learned that P2N2222A and 2N2222A are not the same and at the very least, they have different pin layouts. After flipping Q1 around in my circuit, everything works beautifully; finally now, the world makes sense!

Comment: At a quick glance I'm concerned about both gates being pulled upt to 12 V when on of the sources is at 5.2 V. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Is Q1 an actual 2N2222? Triple-check the pinout and maybe do a diode test on each of the PN junctions to check it's OK.

Comment: Where are you confirming both are off -- I see a measurement of Vgs but not Id or Vout, did you check these? What are the load resistances, is the fan really megohms? | Igss is max +/-0.1uA, and 2N2222 (is it really the ancient (non-'A') metal can version..?) needs to be well cut off to ensure no voltage drop across a 1M pull-up; 100k or less would be more typical here, or a CMOS driver if bias current must be minimized.

Comment: Also you wrote 2N2222 but linked P2N2222A, which notice has a different pinout (C and E swapped) compared to traditional JEDEC TO-92 parts (e.g. PN2222A, 2N3904, etc.). Could E-B breakdown be limiting the voltage?

Comment: @Transistor, thanks for thinking about it; would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @TimWilliams and Transistor, you both questioned Q1. The markings say 2N2222A. In fact, it is identical to this picture: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51DgAxkjxNL._SX522_.jpg

How did I miss the "P" in the datasheet? https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809200018_ST-Semtech-2N2222A_C118536.pdf looks more like it and I see the E and C are swapped.

Comment: @TimWilliams, at first I had the fan only connected and noticed it not going off. I then disconnected the fan and just measured the voltages by probing.

At `drain1`, irrespective of GPIO state, I get 12.25V and at `drain2`, I get 5.177V and 5.160V for HIGH and LOW.

Comment: Thanks for the HUGE pointer regarding the wrong datasheet; funny thing is I am using my new glasses! I will flip Q1 and probe and report back.

I am still confused as to why M2 didn't shut things off.

Comment: @Transistor and TimWilliams, that was it. I was using the wrong datasheet. After flipping the 2N2222A around, everything is great. Now, I am reading 11.31V at the gate which translates to 12.25V. The MOSFETs are putting out 12.25V and 5.2V when GPIO is HIGH and 0 when LOW.

Thank you both.

Comment: @Miki. It's good to hear things working out! I remain mystified about why there are two TO-92 package pinouts like this. I go back to when everything was in a TO-18 package (the `real` 2N2222/A device.) I still have a box of those from when I was much younger. I was shocked when seeing the PN2222A in the TO-92 package and I simply refused to buy them. (Made a promise to myself never to buy them, which of course I broke when the TO-18 price hit the roof!) I have a box of old 2N2219A in TO-39. These have heat sinks available for them! Consider those too. ('A' type is slightly higher Vceo.)

Comment: Congratulations. You can post your update as an answer and after a delay (minutes / hours - I  can't remember) you can accept that as the solution so that the 'bot doesn't periodically bring it up as an unsolved question. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Transistor thanks but it was you who questioned the correctness of Q1 first. You should get the credit. Merry Christmas to you too. I will wait for you to post something and I will mark it.

Comment: @periblepsis hahaha. Thanks.

Comment: @Miki, you need the rep more than I do so go ahead. You also had the manners to report back on the fix so +1 for that.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks. <3

Comment: You get +10 rep for every upvote. At 50 you'll be able to post comments on other people's questions and answers.

Comment: @Transistor good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some very sharp-eyed geniuses, @Transistor and @TimWilliams, who questioned if Q1 was 2N2222A or P2N222A, I realized that I was using 2N2222A but referencing the datasheet for P2N222A.

The correct [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809200018_ST-Semtech-2N2222A_C118536.pdf) for 2N2222A, shows that the pin arrangement is opposite that of P2N222A. After flipping Q1 around to correct the connections, the circuit works beautifully and as expected.